# Maintain row names while merge 2 dataframes

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 dataframes, I merge them and I want to maintain rownames of the first dataframe `df1a`

```
df1a = data.frame(Customer = c(1:8),  Product = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 8 )])
df1b = data.frame(Customer = c(11:18), Product = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 8 )])
rownames(df1a)<-LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 8 )]
merge(df1a, y = df1b, by = "Product")
```

Comment: `df1a$rn <- rownames(df1a)` ... then merge ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `dplyr` - `tibble` approach can be,

```
library(tidyverse)

column_to_rownames(left_join(rownames_to_column(df1a), df1b, by = 'Product'), 'rowname')
```

> ```
>   Customer.x Product Customer.y
> A          1       A         11
> B          2       B         12
> C          3       C         13
> D          4       D         14
> E          5       E         15
> F          6       F         16
> G          7       G         17
> H          8       H         18
> ```

Comment: Why the change of heart :+)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It wasn't an exact dupe and most I found were for filtering rather than merging... :)